# Given the same callback implementation, abstract function calls

Tags: swift

Assuming I have 2 functions `foo` and `bar` defined below.

```
func foo(completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void)
func bar(a: Int, completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void)
```

Then I have 2 different functions that use `foo` and `bar`

```
func doSomethingWithFoo() {
    foo { response in
        handleResponse(response)
    }
}

func doSomethingWithBar() {
    bar(a: 42) { response in
        handleResponse(response)
    }
}
```

`doSomethingWithFoo` and `doSomethingWithBar` are very similar. They do the exact same thing with `response` they get in the `completion` callback.

My question is: is there a way in Swift to generalize `doSomethingWithFoo` and `doSomethingWithBar`? Maybe something in line with the following.

```
func doSomething(<???>) {
    <???> { response in
        handleResponse(response)
    }
}
```

`<???>` is a placeholder for passing either `foo` or `bar` or even any other function that also accepts a callback of type `(Response) -> Void`.

I'll appreciate any help/insights. Thanks.

Comment: Can you combine `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: Can you clarify, @matt? Thanks.

Comment: Do `foo` and `bar` do the same thing? If so, can you turn them into a single `foobar`?

Comment: Another question: You say "generalize", but how is this generalized version supposed to know whether to call `foo` or `bar`?

Comment: They don't do the same thing. The only common thing is the `completion` callback. But the `doSomething...` functions do the same thing with the callbacks.

Comment: To your last question, that's part of what I want to figure out by posting here :). @matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a function like this :

```
func doSomething(fooBar: (_ completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) -> Void) -> Void {
    fooBar(handleResponse)
}
```

Which you would call like this:

```
doSomething(fooBar: { bar(a: 42, completion: $0) })
doSomething(fooBar: foo)
```

Comment: This is called [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).